# How should a RESTful server save user submitted images to file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javax.imageio

Currently, I am using ImageIO.write() in order to write to file. However, this method opens up a Java App on my computer, which then forcefully aborts the Bootstrap process if closed, thereby killing the 'server'. I'm testing locally, using IntelliJ, and the termination of the Bootstrap process means that we are unable to test the functionality without rebooting the server.

My method is below. It runs on an API call from our front-end.

```
/**
 * Saves image to database, assuming that the input is not null or empty.
 * @param filename name of file.
 * @param fileext extension of file.
 * @param uri uri in string form.
 */
public static void saveImageToDisk(String filename, String fileext, String uri) {
    try {
        String[] components = uri.split(",");
        String img64 = components[1];
        byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(img64);
        BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));    
        File outputfile = new File(IMAGESTORAGEFOLDER + filename + "." + fileext);
        ImageIO.write(bfi, fileext, outputfile);
        bfi.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

My question is as follows: How can I save an image (from Raw Data) to file without the server aborting? If my code can be adapted with minimal rewrite, what other improvements can I make to robustify my existing code? I would like a solution with no external dependencies (relying entirely on standard Java libraries).

I am on MacOSX, running IntelliJ IDEA CE. Our server runs with Spark and uses Maven.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using ImageIO shouldn't kill the bootstrap process. You may want to investigate why it happened.

Comment: Not directly related to the "aborting" issue, but: You really shouldn't use `ImageIO` for this at all. It will work much faster and be more compatible if you just write the `decodedBytes` array directly to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImageIO.write() [...] method opens up a Java App on my computer

The issue here is that when you use the `ImageIO` class, it will also initialize the AWT because of some dependencies in the Java2D class hierarchy. This causes the Java launcher on OS X to also open up an icon in the dock and some other things, and I believe this is what you experience. There's really no new Java application being launched.

You can easily avoid this by passing a system property to the Java launcher at startup, telling it to run in "headless" mode. This is usually appropriate for a server process. Pass the following on the command line (or in the IntelliJ launch dialog):

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Read more about [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) from Oracle's pages. Headless mode is the cross-platform way of doing this. There's also an OS X/MacOS specific way to hide the icon from the dock (`-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true`, but I don't recommend that here.

***However, for your use case it's better to avoid the usage of ImageIO altogether.*** It's easier, more compatible, faster, and uses less memory as a bonus. Simply write the Base64 decoded bytes directly to disk. There's no need to treat a file containing an image differently from any other file in this case.

You can rewrite your method as follows:

```
public static void saveImageToDisk(String filename, String fileext, String uri) {
    try {
        String[] components = uri.split(",");
        String img64 = components[1];
        byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(img64);
        File outputfile = new File(IMAGESTORAGEFOLDER, filename + "." + fileext);
        Paths.write(outputFile.toPath(), decodedBytes);
    } catch(Exception e) {  
        // You really shouldn't swallow this exception, but I'll leave that to you...
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it still be possible to render the output file as an image directly from HTML? I.E. will the new file be treated as a proper png/jpg if I do this?

Comment: The file contents should be exactly what it was at the sending end. So it only depends on whether the file was a proper PNG/JPEG in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

After running multiple users at the same time, running the process multiple times, etc, it seems to just be an artifact of either Java's ImageIO or IntelliJ. As long as the new process is not closed, Bootstrap continues to run properly, even if multiple browsers try to upload images, etc.